# How can I set up expectations for event registration on a multimock

Tags: rhino-mocks

I am using `RhinoMocks 3.6` and would like to use the multimock feature to implement both a class and a interface.

```cs
var mocks = new MockRepository();
var project = mocks.StrictMultiMock(
                      typeof(Project),
                      typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged));
using (mocks.Record())
{
     ((INotifyCollectionChanged)project).CollectionChanged += null;
     LastCall.Constraints(Is.NotNull()).Repeat.Any();
}
```

The `LastCall` is working though. I get this message :

> System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Could you share some of the method under test?

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually checked that the Project class has methods you can override as the error message indicates?  I'll assume you have. :-)

I'd suggest you switch to using the AAA syntax instead of record/replay as shown here:

I assume you're wanting to know if the class under test reacts the right way when the CollectionChanged event is fired? If that's the case, you can do it something like this:

```
var project = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Project, INotifyPropertyChanged>();
project.Expect(p => p.SomeMethod())
   .Repeat.Any()
   .Raise(p => ((INotifyCollectionChanged)p).CollectionChanged += null,p,new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs());
```